# How to limit echo string in foreach loop

Tags: php, loops

I'm trying to Slice array but need help in following codes

```
$targetCountries = array("BR","FR","IN","US");
$sliced_array = array_slice($targetCountries, 1, 3);
foreach($sliced_array as $sliced_array){
  echo $sliced_array.',';
}
```

here I want to echo "**,**" only for two times.
The current output is `FR,IN,US,`

Desired Output `FR,IN,US`. I don't want that "**,**" at the end

And How to print this variable outside of the loop as well like in HTML tag?

Comment: You can simply build the string inside the foreach and echo after the loop is completed. Check for empty and use the trim() function before echoing out. This makes it much simpler to read and understand. And from the comments in your accepted answer I hope you got the answer for "How to print this variable outside of the loop as well like in HTML tag?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is simpler and cleaner rather than using loop, `count`, and extra variable:

```
$targetCountries = array("BR","FR","IN","US");
$slicedarray = array_slice($targetCountries, 1, 3);
echo implode(', ', $slicedarray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code :

```
$targetCountries = array("BR","FR","IN","US");
$slicedarray = array_slice($targetCountries, 1, 3);
foreach($slicedarray as $k=>$sliced_array){
    echo (count($slicedarray) == ($k+1))? $sliced_array : $sliced_array.',';
}
```

Comment: can you tell me one more thing? How to print this variable outside of the loop as well like in HTML tag?

Comment: Concatenate to a `var`

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use this way:

```
$targetCountries = array("BR","FR","IN","US");
$slicedarray = array_slice($targetCountries, 1, 3);
foreach($slicedarray as $element){
    echo ($element == end($slicedarray))? $element : $element.',';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code also :

```
$targetCountries = array("BR","FR","IN","US");
$sliced_array = array_slice($targetCountries, 1, 3);
foreach($sliced_array as $k=>$sliced_array){
    echo ($k == 0)? $sliced_array : ','.$sliced_array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try by keeping a counter. So, if the counter is 0, it will not print the comma(,). SO the first element will not have a comma before it. Then the next element onwards, there will be a comma put. 
Try the code below.

````
$targetCountries = array("BR","FR","IN","US");
$sliced_array = array_slice($targetCountries, 1, 3);
$cnt=0;
foreach($sliced_array as $sliced_array){
  if($cnt>0){
    echo ',';
  }
  echo $sliced_array;
  $cnt++;
}
```
````